# not able to send the data from one module component to another module component

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I would like to send the boolean value to true to another module component where I shall set the `*ngIf` value to true to enable the html content. It's navigating to the another component, but not able to enable the html content. I have tried viewchild,emitters,input, output but not able to achieve the desired outcome.

Calling component:

```
SuccessGet(res) {
    this.logs = res;

    for(let item of this.logs)
    {
        if(item._email == this.log._email && item._password == this.log._password)
        {
            alert("Login Successful");

            this.wt.LoginCall(true);     // here calling the other module component
        }
    }

    this.log = new LoginModel();
}
```

Called component:

```
export class WeatherComponent {
      title = 'TemperatureApp';

      //@Input() messagetochild_weather ;//to get the message from parent

      showweather : boolean = false;
      // showweather : boolean = false;

      bus : BusinessLogic = new BusinessLogic();
      WeatherModel : Weather = new Weather();
      WeatherModels : Array<Weather> = new Array<Weather>();
      num : number = 0;

      LoginCall(item : boolean) 
      {
          //this.ngAfterViewInit();
          this.showweather = item;
      }

      ngAfterViewInit(item : any): void
      {
          this.WeatherModels = this.bus.Load(); 
      }
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf=showweather class="card">//here i am using *ngIf
  <h3 class="card-header text-center font-weight-bold text-uppercase py-4">Editable table</h3>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div id="table" class="table-editable">
      <span class="table-add float-right mb-3 mr-2"><a href="#!" class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"
            aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span>
      <table class=" table table-bordered table-responsive-md table-striped text-center table-responsive-sm" style="border-block-end-color:dodgerblue">
        <tr style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255)">
          <th class="text-center">Area Code</th>
          <th class="text-center" >Date</th>
          <th class="text-center">Country</th>
          <th class="text-center">State</th>
          <th class="text-center">City</th>
          <th class="text-center">Temperature</th>
          <th class="text-center">Action</th>
          <th class="text-center">Action</th>
        </tr>
```

Comment: What is `this.wt`? Where is the `*ngIf` you're trying to use?

Comment: @ user184994 : wt is an instance of the component to which i am calling. Edited the content to show the html content where i am using *ngIf.

Comment: Interacting the with component directly is not the correct way to do it. Instead, you should create a service to handle the interaction, as suggeted by @SureshKumarAriya https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 1):

You should use Subject/BehaviorSubject.

**Service:**

```
private statusValue = new Subject<Boolean>();
statusValue$ = this.statusValue.asObservable();

updateStatus(status){
  this.statusValue.next(status);
}
```

**Component 1:**

```
this.service.updateStatus(true);
```

**Component2:**

```
this.service.statusValue$.subscribe(value=>{console.log(value);}
```